# get_pages not returning any results or error when get_posts works

Tags: get-posts, pages

I have a code sample that works with get_posts but I now need do with get_pages so I can get grandchildren in the results set:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment'
        ) );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', true );

            echo '<dl class="' . $class . ' gallery-item masonry-brick">    <dt class="gallery-icon">' . $thumbimg . '</dt></dl>';
        }

    }
```

When I substitute get_posts with get_pages (all else the same) there are no results. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or why this should be?

Thanks!!!

Steve

Comment: Have you tried `get_posts()` with `'post_type' => 'page'`?

Comment: I hadn't but I was looking to build a gallery - should I use page?

Comment: I am not sure what want: attachments or pages?

Comment: hmmm - i want to display a gallery of attachments and it's children/granchildren

Comment: galleries are not (yet) post types, and attachments are not a hierarchical post type. Both cannot have children, and `get_pages()` returns always `FALSE` for non-hierarchical post types. Try to explain your goal better – in your question, not in a comment, please. :)

Comment: ok will do - at least this has helped to clarify the misunderstanding i had...thanks